# I can't enable iCloud backup on my phone

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, ios

My iCloud backup is currently off.  So I go into Settings/iCloud/Backup and switch the iCloud backup slider to on.

It comes up with warning stating that the phone will no longer back up to my computer automatically when I sync with iTunes.  I say Ok.  Then the phone thinks for 2 seconds and comes up with an error saying `iCloud Backup Failed`, `There was a problem enablling iCloud Backup'.

Why can't I enable backup?

Comment: Could you provide more details? (iOS version, iPhone type, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the same function through iTunes on your Mac. Just plug it in, go into the iPhone's settings, and set it up from there. May have better results.

[image]